# how can i reduce space for sectionIndexTitlesForTableView

Tags: xcode, header, tableview, footer

i have a tableview with footer and header and a sectionindextitle. My problem is that i cant see the first value and the last one. how can i start the sectiontindextitle after the header position and before the footer position ?

Answer (score 0):

The index appears on top of the tableView layer and since the table view header and footer scroll.  It doesn't make sense that the table view header or footer would change the size of the fixed index.

To do what you want, you would need to move the header and footer out of the table view and add separate views, with a smaller table view.